# Android OpenGl ES2.0 sgxpb.c:965: GrowPerContextPB: PB Limit reached

Tags: android, native, opengl-es-2.0, nexus-s

When we are running our opengles2.0 based application on Android based phone google nexus-s, we got a warning on logcat saying "sgxpb.c:965: GrowPerContextPB: PB Limit reached". We saw rendering initially, but after the mentioned warning, there is no rendering seen ( blank screen). 
Help me please

Best Regards,